# How to get a pages TabView (PageTabViewStyle) to be ordered backwards?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I wish for my pages TabView to be ordered backwards. This is the code I have currently:

```
struct BackwardsPageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("Hello")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Text("My")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Text("Friend")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}
```

This is the desired result I wish to have:

[image: Desired result.]

How would I go about achieving this result without changing the order of my code?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  Without knowing the why, the simplest solution seems to just flip the order, whether it be manually or programmatically...

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a default tab selection using a `tag` identifier like so:

```
struct BackwardsPageView: View {
    
    @State private var selection = 3

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection:$selection) {
            Text("Friend")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .tag(1)
            Text("My")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .tag(2)
            Text("Hello")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .tag(3)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}
```

You'll also have to change the order of your `Text` titles as well.